# Stuck at the same point when passing SQL File to SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I am passing a sql file to sqlplus through this command:

```
sqlplus -s user/pass@//10.8.249.22:1521/homhyp @E:\PQS\Integracao_14\LDCSVDP\regiao\BIN\merge_tables.sql
```

But it gets stuck and seem to be doing nothing.

The content of my sql file is:

```
MERGE INTO TB_DP_REGIAO B
USING TMP_DP_REGIAO P
ON (P.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE = B.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET B.DS_PLANNING_CODE = CASE WHEN B.DT_LOAD < P.DT_LOAD THEN 
P.DS_PLANNING_CODE ELSE B.DS_PLANNING_CODE END,
                             B.DT_LOAD = CASE WHEN B.DT_LOAD < P.DT_LOAD THEN P.DT_LOAD 
ELSE B.DT_LOAD END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(DS_PROTHEUS_CODE, DS_PLANNING_CODE, DT_LOAD) VALUES
(P.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE, P.DS_PLANNING_CODE, P.DT_LOAD)
/
EXIT
```

The sqlplus is called from within a BAT file and it shows nothing until I press `Ctrl+C`. It only shows:

```
E:\PQS\Integracao_14\LDCSVDP\regiao\BIN>sqlplus user/pass@// 10.8.249.22:1521/homhyp @E:\PQS\Integracao_14\LDCSVDP\regiao\BIN\merge_tables.sq l 

    SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 20 13:34:15 2014 
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle. All rights reserved. 
    Connected to: 
    Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For testing .. if you make a syntax error in your query, what happens?

Comment: René is right, you do need an `exit` if you load/run the file with `@` like that; but out of interest, what output do you get when you press `ctrl-c`? That sounds like the merge is still running - it would say something like 'use cancelled current operation' if so. If it does say that, do you have any uncommitted changes to that table in another session?

Comment: When I press Ctrl+C it appears `Terminado batch job (Y/N)`

Comment: How should I use this `exit` command? I made some attempts but none worked...

Comment: @LucasRezende - your comment on René's answer showed a `7`, which is missing from your question edit; if that exists, it is on a line on its own, right? That implies your statement isn't being executed, which doesn't match the file you showed - whatever is in `merge_tables.sql` has six lines without a semicolon at the end, despite you showing one in the question. You need that semi-colon, or a `/` on the next line on it own; then on the next line `exit` on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused now about what you're actually running. Your `merge_tables.sql` script should contain either:

```
MERGE INTO TB_DP_REGIAO B
USING TMP_DP_REGIAO P
ON (P.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE = B.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET B.DS_PLANNING_CODE = CASE WHEN B.DT_LOAD < P.DT_LOAD
    THEN P.DS_PLANNING_CODE ELSE B.DS_PLANNING_CODE END,
  B.DT_LOAD = CASE WHEN B.DT_LOAD < P.DT_LOAD
    THEN P.DT_LOAD ELSE B.DT_LOAD END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (DS_PROTHEUS_CODE, DS_PLANNING_CODE, DT_LOAD)
  VALUES (P.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE, P.DS_PLANNING_CODE, P.DT_LOAD);
EXIT
```

Or:

```
MERGE INTO TB_DP_REGIAO B
USING TMP_DP_REGIAO P
ON (P.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE = B.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET B.DS_PLANNING_CODE = CASE WHEN B.DT_LOAD < P.DT_LOAD
    THEN P.DS_PLANNING_CODE ELSE B.DS_PLANNING_CODE END,
  B.DT_LOAD = CASE WHEN B.DT_LOAD < P.DT_LOAD
    THEN P.DT_LOAD ELSE B.DT_LOAD END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (DS_PROTHEUS_CODE, DS_PLANNING_CODE, DT_LOAD)
  VALUES (P.DS_PROTHEUS_CODE, P.DS_PLANNING_CODE, P.DT_LOAD)
/
EXIT
```

You either need a statement separator (`;`) at the end of the command, or `/` on the next line on its own (but not both or it will execute twice). And then as René said you need to exit the script at the end.

If you have uncommitted changes to the table you are merging into, `TB_DP_REGIAO`, then the merge itself might appear to hang as it waits for locks to be released - that will happen when those other changes are committed or rolled back, but this merge will wait indefinitely for that to happen. You won't see an error, it'll just do nothing very much, which seems to be what's happening here if you do have the command execution (via `;` or `/`) and the `exit`.

Comment: I just updated my question to put exactly how it is now, and it is as the second option you wrote. It is still stuck at the same point as shown in the question and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Are there any other way for me to pass a sql file to sqlplus?

Comment: OK, does `ctrl-c` still give the 'terminate batch job' message, or does it drop you to an `SQL>` prompt (without the `-s` flag)? Do you have uncommitted data in the table you're merging into, `TB_DP_REGIAO`, in another session - SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, or some other client?

Comment: It's getting the file, and if it's as you show now then it should be running the `MERGE`; if it's actually stalled on that command then something it locking a row it wants to update, or there are pending inserts that affect a PK/UK, etc.

Comment: You are right! I tested the SQL on SQL Developer before putting it in a file and forgot to commit it. I just commited and runned again and worked! Thanks a lok for your help and sorry for such a basic stuff. By the way, I have one last question: For this not to happen again, do I need to put a `COMMIT` at the end of my sql file or sqlplus auto commits the statement?

Comment: @LucasRezende - by default SQL*Plus will commit on exit, but it's better to do it explicitly. Other clients don't and it shows the intent, and it's a good habit for when you're making changes somewhere else. But, in some cases, you might want to also have [`WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm) at the start of the file, so you don't commit something you didn't mean to if there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot one more time for the solution of my problem and the useful tips!

Answer (score 3):

add an `exit` after your sql statement.

I assume that the statement does what it is supposed to do. Then it waits for further statements to be typed in. Since you started SQL*Plus with `-s`, you won't notice.

Comment: Is it just write `exit` at the end?

Comment: I removed the `-s` and runned again. This is what appears to me then: 
`E:\PQS\Integracao_14\LDCSVDP\regiao\BIN>sqlplus  user/pass@//
10.8.249.22:1521/homhyp @E:\PQS\Integracao_14\LDCSVDP\regiao\BIN\merge_tables.sq
l

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 20 13:34:15 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

  7 `

Comment: I just updated my question. Thanks for the advice. About the somicolon, it had a `/` at the end but already removed and the `7` is not shown anymore. Anyway, it is still stuck in that point and nothing happens. Is there any other way for me to pass this sql file to be executed by `sqlplus`?